# Rewrite base url to show content of cms page

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-6, httpd.conf, isapi-rewrite

Trying to rewrite a base url e.g http://beta.mydomain.com to http://beta.mydomain.com/cms/index.cfm/new-home but want browser to show base url not the cms url.

Im trying this in isapi httpd config file:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /cms/index.cfm/new-home [NC,L]
```

but it simply redirects to http://beta.mydomain.com/cms/index.cfm/new-home
which is correct except that the browser must show http://beta.mydomain.com/ not the cms part.

We are using IIS 6 with isapi module installed. Thats the only thing I know about the server (but I have access to server). Is that possible? If not then what other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea: Load http://beta.mydomain.com/cms/index.cfm/new-home in an iFrame.

For example if someone browser to base URL i.e. http://beta.mydomain.com/ then load http://beta.mydomain.com/cms/index.cfm/new-home page in iframe.

It should be like a condition at top of your index page.

```
if (only baseURL) {
   iFrame: Load http://beta.mydomain.com/cms/index.cfm/new-home 
}
```

Hope this help :)